# How to pass values from one function to the other using an array variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Hello I have a function that passes values to other functions using javascript without reloading page.

The first action of the javascript below gets values from a form and sends to php via a call back function formbuilder_ajax_call. In my php script i return these form values as an array so i can call it in other functions. Below is my code:

Javascript

```
   jQuery("#button_to_load_data").click(function() {
   var email = $("#email").val();
   var other_email = $("#other_email").val();
   var subject = $("#subject").val();
   var sender = $("#sender").val();
   var message = $("#message").val();
   var form_name = $("#form_name").val();
   var content = getPlainHtml();
  //    alert(content);
 var data = {
    'action'   : 'formbuilder_ajax_call', // the name of your PHP function!
    'form_content' : content,           // another random value we'd like to pass
    'email' : email,
    'other_email' : other_email,
    'subject' : subject,
    'sender' : sender,
    'message' : message,
    'form_name' : form_name,
    
    };
    
    
   var data1 = {
    'action'   : 'make_short_code'
    }; 

 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    jQuery("#receiving_div_id").html(response);
 });


 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data1, function(response) {
    jQuery("#receiving_div_id").html(response);
 });

 });
```

PHP

```
 function formbuilder_ajax_call(){

 $form_content = trim($_POST['form_content']); // these values are from a form
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $other_email = trim($_POST['other_email']);
 $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
 $sender = trim($_POST['sender']);
 $message = trim($_POST['message']);
 $form_name = trim($_POST['form_name']);

 $form_array = array(); 

 $form_array = array(

 "form_content" => $form_content,
 "email" => $email,
 "other_email" => $other_email,
 "subject" => $subject,
 "sender" => $sender,
 "message" => $message,
 "form_name" => $form_name,

  );  


  return  $form_array;
  }


  function make_short_code() { 

  $get_mailinfo = formbuilder_ajax_call();


  var_dump($get_mailinfo);

  }
```

I am using var_dump to see the content being passed in make_short_code but its only the array key values from formbuilder_ajax_call() that are passed and not the content values that was stored in the array. However the values are passed in the

Comment: In your second ajax request (where you call `make_short_code`), you're not passing any values. When posting data, it will only exist during _that single request_. An ajax request is just an ordinary request (it just happens in the background). I don't see why you need two at all. Remove the second ajax request and change the action in the first to be `make_short_code` instead. There's no need call PHP twice.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the first ajax request is meant to get values from form through javascript and into php variables through the form_builder_ajax () function and return an array so that i can tjen use the second function to call get the values from the first function. HowHowever the keys are carried in the second function. Keys like form_content,form_name but their values are left out. Any ideas? Will using the makeshortcode in the first ajax request get everything to work?

Comment: Please read my comment again. I explained why that approach doesn't work. I'll try it again anyway: When the first request is over and you got a response in your ajax function, PHP have already thrown those values away. When you make the second request, it's a brand new request starting from scratch. So you need to post those variables in that request as well, which you aren't doing. Send the values to the request that actually will use them. PHP doesn't remember posted data between requests.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i got you clearly. I was thinking i could get the values into an array in the first function and return the array. I did it so for another application but it was not through ajax. I will try what you said.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson your solution worked. Thank you very much. I am unable to flag your answer correct. ANy help with that

Answer (score 0):

try `json_encode($form_array)` in php script and add `"JSON" as 4th param` in jquery ajax. That way you can access data sent from php script in callback e.g. `response.email`

Comment: please can you explain more if possible with some code.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: @Djouonang have you figured out yet?

Comment: i have figured it out